# Magento 2.2.2 getting error unable to process binding if: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, mini-cart

I am getting an error like

> unable to process binding if: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }

in magento 2.2.2

I tried below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I also remove my overridden template code of minicart.phtml file in my custom theme

Still, I faced this error, anyone has any idea about this error?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just short out this issue, Problem was I override Magento_Theme's default layout xml file

and I also modify to `<container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">` tag that's why minicart was mis behaving

Comment: Same issue and the same reason, but with a different block in the template XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this issue may occure becuase of theme override some core file so just compare magento core file `vendor/magento/module_checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html .`